# matching only if target 'cell' is NA

Tags: r, match

I have the following two data.frames opcat and polity.

```
opcat <- data.frame(country = rep(LETTERS[1:5]), date.ratification = c(2003,2004,2005,NA,NA),        date.accession = c(NA,NA,NA,2000,2006))

opcat  

polity <- data.frame(year = rep((2000:2007), 7), country = rep(LETTERS[1:7],8), polity.score = sample(10, 56, replace=TRUE))

polity <- polity[order(polity$country, polity$year),]
polity
```

I want to insert the polity.score of the dateframe polity to the data.frame opcat for the year in which a country 'ratified' (= date.ratified) or 'acceeded' (= date.accession).

for ratification

```
opcat$polity.score <- polity$polity.score[match(interaction(opcat$country, opcat$date.ratification), interaction(polity$country, polity$year))]
opcat

  country date.ratification date.accession polity.score
1       A              2003             NA           10
2       B              2004             NA            2
3       C              2005             NA           10
4       D                NA           2000           NA
5       E                NA           2006           NA
```

for accesssion

```
 opcat$polity.score <- polity$polity.score[match(interaction(opcat$country, opcat$date.accession), interaction(polity$country, polity$year))]
 opcat

  country date.ratification date.accession polity.score
1       A              2003             NA           NA
2       B              2004             NA           NA
3       C              2005             NA           NA
4       D                NA           2000            9
5       E                NA           2006            7
```

A country has either a date for ratification or for accession (not both). Since the matching for accession would fill the results for ratification with NA, I tried the following modification:

```
 opcat$polity.score[is.na(opcat$date.ratification)] <- polity$polity.score[match(interaction(opcat$country, opcat$date.accession), interaction(polity$country, polity$year))]
 opcat
```

But this doesn't work. I get the error message " number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". How can I match the scores into the same variable without overwriting them?

The final result should be

```
  country date.ratification date.accession polity.score
1       A              2003             NA           10
2       B              2004             NA            2
3       C              2005             NA           10
4       D                NA           2000           9
5       E                NA           2006           7
```

I would think that this shouldn't be that difficult.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `year` to opcat, and perform a standard merge:

```
opcat$year <- with(opcat, ifelse(is.na(date.ratification), date.accession, date.ratification))
merge(opcat,polity)
```